# How to set the background color of target cells in a jtable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I don't want to set the background color for all the cells in the jtable, just the ones I choose.  How do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

you need to use a [custom renderer](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Comment: Isn't there an easier faster way to do this?

Comment: unfortunately not. The renderer is what handles painting each individual table cell

Comment: theres an example and some discussion here http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=53764

Answer (score 2):

You might find the concept presented in [Table Row Renderering](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) easier to implement. Maybe keep a Set of Points (representing a cell you want to color). Or maybe even a Map of Points and Colors.

Answer (score 1):

```
    final JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
    table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            int selectedHeader = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(table
                    .columnAtPoint(mouseEvent.getPoint()));

            table.getColumn(table.getColumnName(selectedHeader))
                    .setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
                        public void setBackground(Color c) {
                            super.setBackground(Color.blue);
                        }
                    });
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a custom CellRenderer and call it in your custom JTable's getCellRenderer(int col, int rol) method.

See http://self-reference.com/tech/swing.html for a good example.